# I'm having some trouble with a python Bot, like the driver is not being recognized

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

Please can someone tell me why I'm getting this error with this code? I am trying to run a whatsapp bot. However, when I run my code, I get the error below.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lwyzb\OneDrive\Documentos\Bot whatsapp\wppBot.py", line 32, in <module>
    bot.MsgSend()
  File "C:\Users\lwyzb\OneDrive\Documentos\Bot whatsapp\wppBot.py", line 16, in MsgSend
    self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
AttributeError: 'WhatsappBot' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class WhatsappBot:
    def _init_(self):
        self.msg = "Bom dia famiiiilia"
        self.groups = ["Churras ??/?? ", "PARÇAS (Nova formação)", "Parças incorporated"]
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')

    def MsgSend(self):
          # <span dir="auto" title="PARÇAS (Nova formação)" class="_3ko75 _5h6Y_ _3Whw5">PARÇAS (Nova formação)</span>
          # <div tabindex="-1" class="_3uMse">
          # <span data-testid="send" data-icon="send" class="">
          self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
          time.sleep(30)
          for group in self.groups:
              group = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='{group}']")
              time.sleep(3)
              group.click()
              chatBox = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3uMse')
              time.sleep(3)
              chatBox.click()
              chatBox.send_keys(self.msg)
              send = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-icon='send']")
              time.sleep(3)
              send.click()
              time.sleep(5)

bot = WhatsappBot()
bot.MsgSend()
```

Answer (score 4):

You're `init` function is named incorrectly - it should be `__init__`, not `_init_`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class WhatsappBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = "Bom dia famiiiilia"
        self.groups = ["Churras ??/?? ", "PARÇAS (Nova formação)", "Parças incorporated"]
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')

    def MsgSend(self):
          # <span dir="auto" title="PARÇAS (Nova formação)" class="_3ko75 _5h6Y_ _3Whw5">PARÇAS (Nova formação)</span>
          # <div tabindex="-1" class="_3uMse">
          # <span data-testid="send" data-icon="send" class="">
          self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
          time.sleep(30)
          for group in self.groups:
              group = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='{group}']")
              time.sleep(3)
              group.click()
              chatBox = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3uMse')
              time.sleep(3)
              chatBox.click()
              chatBox.send_keys(self.msg)
              send = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-icon='send']")
              time.sleep(3)
              send.click()
              time.sleep(5)

bot = WhatsappBot()
bot.MsgSend()
```

Python only looks for the `__init__` function - since you accidentally forgot those two underscores, Python didn't realize that was supposed to be the initializer, and so it didn't run it.

Comment: Thanks alot! All makes sense now haha

Answer (score 2):

Everyting is OK but LOL you are missing the two underscores of `__init__`, so class does not get properly initialised:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class WhatsappBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = "Bom dia famiiiilia"
        self.groups = ["Churras ??/?? ", "PARÇAS (Nova formação)", "Parças incorporated"]
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('lang=pt-br')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')

    def MsgSend(self):
          # <span dir="auto" title="PARÇAS (Nova formação)" class="_3ko75 _5h6Y_ _3Whw5">PARÇAS (Nova formação)</span>
          # <div tabindex="-1" class="_3uMse">
          # <span data-testid="send" data-icon="send" class="">
          self.driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
          time.sleep(30)
          for group in self.groups:
              group = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='{group}']")
              time.sleep(3)
              group.click()
              chatBox = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3uMse')
              time.sleep(3)
              chatBox.click()
              chatBox.send_keys(self.msg)
              send = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-icon='send']")
              time.sleep(3)
              send.click()
              time.sleep(5)

bot = WhatsappBot()
bot.MsgSend()
```

Comment: Thanks alot haha I went back and changed the method haha But great! Thanks for the help